# how to fix the pip install error in python 3.7 with Pycharm and window 11

Tags: python, pip

I wrote terminal 'pip install osgeo' to add 'osgeo' library.
But I always get the same error message as below.
This problem also can appear when I try 'pip install --upgrade pip'.

---

```
    ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in     _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 333, in run
    reqs, check_supported_wheels=not options.target_dir
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 305, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    skip_reason = self._check_skip_installed(req)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 250, in _check_skip_installed
    self.finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=True)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 901, in find_requirement
    req.name, specifier=req.specifier, hashes=hashes,
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 883, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 828, in find_all_candidates
    project_url, link_evaluator=link_evaluator,
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 792, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 612, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 451, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 166, in _get_html_response
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 421, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 459, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 318, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 549, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\auth.py", line 202, in   __call__
    url, username, password = self._get_url_and_credentials(req.url)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\auth.py", line 178, in _get_url_and_credentials
    username, password = self._get_new_credentials(original_url)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\auth.py", line 142, in _get_new_credentials
    netrc_auth = get_netrc_auth(original_url)
    File "j:\python\goci-ii_navigation\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 204, in get_netrc_auth
    _netrc = netrc(netrc_path).authenticators(host)
    File "C:\python\Lib\netrc.py", line 30, in __init__
    self._parse(file, fp, default_netrc)
    File "C:\python\Lib\netrc.py", line 39, in _parse
    toplevel = tt = lexer.get_token()
    File "C:\python\Lib\shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
    File "C:\python\Lib\shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp949' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I modify 'text_file.py' and 'netrc.py' to add 'encoding = "UTF8"'.
But I didn't solve the error. Could you give me any advice, please??

Comment: Do you have a python installation at `C:\Python` and `J:\Python`?

Comment: yes. at first, I installed in C:/Python.  And then, when I make a new project I set the interpreter in j:'/